# How to Loop and count data field from database with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, loops, foreach

I'm developing a simple survey app that uses Likert Scale to determine the result of the research. But I had some difficulties when retrieving some data set from the database.

Let's say I have the following database as the example:

```
===============================
| id | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5 |
|=============================|
| 1  | 1  | 3  | 2  | 4  | 1  |
|-----------------------------|
| 2  | 3  | 2  | 1  | 3  | 2  |
|-----------------------------|
| 3  | 2  | 3  | 1  | 4  | 2  |
|-----------------------------|
| 4  | 1  | 4  | 4  | 3  | 1  |
|-----------------------------|
| 5  | 4  | 1  | 1  | 3  | 2  |
===============================
```

The q1 means question number 1 and so on. And content of the data as the following:

```
1 = Very Not Satisfied (VNS)
2 = Not Satisfied (NS)
3 = Satisfied (S)
4 = Very Satisfied (VS)
```

So basically I have scale from 1-4. What I want to get is the count of each data scale in each question field like this:

```
    q1  q2  q3  q4  q5
VS  1   1   1   2   0
S   1   2   0   3   0
NS  1   1   1   0   3
VNS 2   1   3   0   2
```

So how can I achieve that in PHP using array loop?

So far, I had tried this:

```
$countSatisfied = array();
$count = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $index = "q" . $i;
    foreach ($all as $keys) {
        if($keys[$index] == 1) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `count(*)` in your sql query so the sql count it for you or use num_rows() if u use mysqli and rowcount() for pdo. this function should never be used at all to count rows in database! Instead, one have to ask a database to count them, and return the result in a single row:

Comment: if you still want to count it in php you can select * and store it in an array. then use `count($array)` to count the array.